How to implement a Monte Carlo Tree Search?
I'm working on a project that involves making a Monte Carlo Tree Search and I'm trying to implement it for Connect 4 before trying to apply it to a more complicated problem.
Here is my code for the game:
class board:
    
    def __init__(self):
        self.board = np.zeros((6,7))
        self.ROW_COUNT = 6
        self.COLUMN_COUNT = 7
        self.game_over = False
        self.turn = 0
        self.value = 0
        
    def isGameOver(self):
        return self.game_over
    
    def whatTurn(self):
        return self.turn
    
    def changeTurn(self):
        self.turn += 1
        self.turn = self.turn % 2
        
    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.value)
    
    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, board):
            return self.value == other.value
        else:
            return False
        
    def drop_piece(self, row, col, piece):
        self.board[row][col]= piece
        
    def is_valid_location(self ,col):
        #if this condition is true we will let the use drop piece here.
        #if not true that means the col is not vacant
        return self.board[5][col]==0
    
    def get_next_open_row(self, col):
        for r in range(self.ROW_COUNT):
            if self.board[r][col]==0:
                return r
    
    def print_board(self):
        print(np.flip(self.board,0))
        
    def winning_move(self, piece):
        # Check horizontal locations for win
        for c in range(self.COLUMN_COUNT-3):
            for r in range(self.ROW_COUNT):
                if self.board[r][c] == piece and self.board[r][c+1] == piece and self.board[r][c+2] == piece and self.board[r][c+3] == piece:
                    self.game_over = True

        # Check vertical locations for win
        for c in range(self.COLUMN_COUNT):
            for r in range(self.ROW_COUNT-3):
                if self.board[r][c] == piece and self.board[r+1][c] == piece and self.board[r+2][c] == piece and self.board[r+3][c] == piece:
                    self.game_over = True

        # Check positively sloped diaganols
        for c in range(self.COLUMN_COUNT-3):
            for r in range(self.ROW_COUNT-3):
                if self.board[r][c] == piece and self.board[r+1][c+1] == piece and self.board[r+2][c+2] == piece and self.board[r+3][c+3] == piece:
                    self.game_over = True

        # Check negatively sloped diaganols
        for c in range(self.COLUMN_COUNT-3):
            for r in range(3, self.ROW_COUNT):
                if self.board[r][c] == piece and self.board[r-1][c+1] == piece and self.board[r-2][c+2] == piece and self.board[r-3][c+3] == piece:
                    self.game_over = True

Now it is my understanding that when I make an instance of a game board and save it to a node in my Monte Carlo Tree, once I have the board drop more pieces for later nodes, the initial node will change too since classes are mutable and the name of the "board" is just referring to the object. Is this the case? If so, any ideas on how I can use this class to make a search tree?

Make a copy of the board?

Unrelated, but why does your drop_piece need row and piece as parameters? The values for these two variables are implied by the current state (namely turn implies piece and get_next_open_row gets you the row).

I see several methods that need to be called to complete a move. I suggest you add the code that actually performs a move in the context of the Monte Carlo search, as now it is unclear what piece is, how you call these methods, ...etc.

Apparently you lost interest in your own question.
